# Duplication in category text php

Tags: php, duplication, txtextcontrol

i want write a code in php that go to txt file in dir "file" and look to line 2 and take category and subject from line 3 for a menu in my site.

```
   function arrayDuplicate($array) 
{ 
return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($array1,array_unique($array1))); 
}

$number =Countdir('file');

for ($i = 1; $i <= $number; $i++) {

$myFile = file; 
$myFile .= '/'; 
$myFile .= $i;
$myFile .= ".txt";

$cat = ReadLine($myFile, 2);
$arr1 .= "'"; 
$arr1 .= $cat; 
$arr1 .= "'"; 
$arr1 .= ","; 
$arr1 .= " "; 
print($arr1);
}
$arr = array($arr1);

$result = arrayDuplicate($arr);
```

in 1.txt
"1
cat1
subject1
file1.pdf
1369947340"

in 2.txt
"2
cat1
subject2
file2.pdf
1369947310"

in 3.txt
"3
cat2
subject3
file3pdf
1369947304"

i want menu cat1 | cat2..
and when you touch cat1 you see subject1 and subject2 ,cat2 see subject3..

My code show me cat1 | cat1 | cat2

Answer (score 0):

This is a very difficult way to do something very easy.

Might I suggest you use a MYSQL database as the source for your menu?

If you insist on doing it the hard way:

Since you know the names of the files, simply create an array containing their names vis:

```
$files=array("/directoryname/1.txt",...etc);
```

wrap your code in a foreach loop on $files.